# Tensorflow transpose of randomly generated tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm practicing with TensorFlow basic commands and I started to use the tf.transpose function. I'm encountering a weird behaviour which I'm not able to explain. If I run this snippet:

```
with tf.Session() as test:
...:     tf.set_random_seed(1)
...:     A = tf.random_normal([2,3],mean=1,stddev=4)
...:     B = tf.transpose(A)
...:     print("A=" + str(A.eval()))
...:     print("B=" + str(B.eval()))
```

I get a print like this:

```
A=[[ 0.59019732 -0.68919742  3.13932252]
   [-2.62436795  1.91452241  6.34897995]]
B=[[ 10.35036469  -0.78370452]
   [  2.15025043   5.39917326]
   [  3.15622997  -4.52096176]]
```

Where does the B value come from? If i run the same but initializing the A tensor to a constant value, integer tensor, I see the transpose as expected... Where am I wrong here?

EDIT: Using the workaround provided by the accepted answer below (thanks!) this works as expected when the code snippet is modified like this:

```
with tf.Session() as test:
...:     tf.set_random_seed(1)
...:     A = tf.random_normal([2,3],mean=1,stddev=4)
...:     B = tf.transpose(A)
...:     print(test.run([A,B]))
```

Comment: This is just a guess, but I imagine it's re-evaluating the random number after it does the transpose: in other words it's not storing values in A, it's storing functions that output random numbers, and then running these functions again when creating B. I imagine if you, say, transpose B now you'll get a third set of numbers that don't match A or B?

Comment: Yes, if I do transpose of B, I get again random numbers. I think you're right explanation of the root cause is correct.

Comment: Cool. I'm not familiar enough with Tensorflow to suggest a workaround I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tensorflow` groups functions and whenever a run is requested, it runs all the operations required for that run.

Now, when the first time you do `A.eval()`, tensorflow sees that it need to initialize it with random numbers for it to output the answer and it does that. Now, when it sees `B.eval()`, it sees that it needs the value of `A` to evaluate `B`, and it needs to initialize `A` with random variables and hence, in the second run, different random variables are assigned to `A`.

To get around this problem, evaluate both `A` and `B` in a single run as

```
A_out, B_out = sess.run([A, B])
```